# 3-level hierarchy with bootstrap scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I want to add another hierarchy level to my [existing 2-level scrollspy](http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/PGYJKB). I've tried nesting it by adding more levels but that didn't work at all.

```
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#GroupASub1">Sub-Group 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#GroupASub2">Sub-Group 2</a></li>
            </ul>
```

What is the best way to do this? Are there working examples of 3-level scrollspy that I haven't found yet?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not very hard to nested to 3rd level just easily follow what you have done for 2nd level and do it for 3rd level.

For instance, I have a demo here http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/dpdvwp which I have forked your work and nested to 3rd level.

I hope this sample code helps.

to clarify: I have changed this part

```
<section id="GroupA" class="group">
            <h3>Group A</h3>
            <div id="GroupASub1" class="subgroup clearfix">
                <h4>Group A Sub 1</h4>
              <hr>
              <div class="clearfix">
              <div id="GroupASubSub1" class="subsubgroup">
                <h4>Group A SubSub 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="GroupASubSub2" class="subsubgroup">
                <h4>Group A SubSub 2</h4>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="GroupASub2" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group A Sub 2</h4>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and

```
 <li>
                <a href="#GroupA">Group A</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#GroupASub1">Sub-Group 1</a>
                  <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#GroupASubSub1">SUBSub-Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#GroupASubSub2">SUbSub-Group 2</a></li>
                </ul>

                  </li>
                    <li><a href="#GroupASub2">Sub-Group 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

and your css code to

```
.group {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
}
.group .subgroup {
    background: orange;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
}
.group .subsubgroup {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;


}
.group .subsubgroup h4 {color:white}
```